# Logistic regression in matlab using mnrfit

Tags: matlab, regression

I'm trying to use the `mnrfit` function but I get the error

`If Y is a column vector, it must contain positive integer category numbers.` .

My data is in a **double** and my Y values are **floats**, e.g. 0.6667. Is there a way that I can adjust my data to be able to use the mnrfit function?

Thanks in advance!
An unexperienced beginner

Comment: You could try to multiply Y by a enough big number, then round the result.

Comment: @Bebs There are [better ways](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54749376/3978545), without having to know how big that number would need to be...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Y` should be a "nominal outcome", i.e. non-continuous, to use `mnrfit`. We don't need to turn `Y` into integers, just categoricals. A categorical array is discrete as far as MATLAB is concerned, regardless whether the categories are represented by double values.

```
X = rand(5,3); % Predictors (should be double or single)
Y = rand(5,1); % Response (doubles, will cause error)

B = mnrfit( X, Y )
% ERROR: If Y is a column vector, it must contain positive integer category numbers. 

B = mnrfit( X, categorical(Y) )
% No error, regression matrix B is output successfully.
```

**Be careful**, if you're expecting a continuous response variable (hence why `Y` is a vector of doubles) then `mnrfit` may not be suitable in the first place!

---

Note the valid data types are specified in the [docs](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/stats/mnrfit.html#btmaowv-Y)

> Y can be one of the following:
>
> - An n-by-k matrix, where Y(i,j) is the number of outcomes of the multinomial category j for the predictor combinations given by X(i,:). In this case, the number of observations are made at each predictor combination.
> - An n-by-1 column vector of scalar integers from 1 to k indicating the value of the response for each observation. In this case, all sample sizes are 1.
> - **An n-by-1 categorical array indicating the nominal or ordinal value of the response for each observation.** In this case, all sample sizes are 1.

Comment: Nice. Indeed it would be nice to have more values to see if they are "connected" like pseudo-continuous or sparse. Who knows...

Comment: @Bebs you can do this with other regression techniques, just not `mnrfit`.

Comment: @Wolfie Thanks! 
I turned my Y into a categorical array which removed the error, however the plot looks wrong.
Is that because Y is continuous and not either 1 or 0? Do you know a function that is suitable for multinomial logistic regression? 
I did a lot of research but can't seem to find a good fit...